# HTML formatting in .php file in phpstorm

Tags: html, phpstorm, indentation

I am using phpStorm 8.0. I have set HTML code formatting settings as under

tab size = 2

indent   = 2

This is working as desired in .html file (see following screenshot from an .html file)

[image: .html file screenshot (desired)]

**But** in .php file it is still using 4 spaces indent (see following screenshot from .php file )

[image: .php file screenshot (not desired)]

How to get same HTML formatting both in .html file and .php file.

Comment: After searching more I have come to know that there is bug filed [**here**](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-17786) on 05 Apr 2013 and it is not fixed till yet....